# How to implement the hbs code from the following ejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, hbs

i want to use:

**<% pizzas.foreach(function(pizza){%>----------------------------------------------------------------html code-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------<%})%>**

this ejs code into hbs code i apply this code:

**{{#each pizzas}}
----------------------------htmlcode----------------------------------------------------------------{{/each}}  but i want to use that function(pizza) also how i apply this plz help!**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars doesn't let you create inline functions.

See [the documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#evaluation-context).

The current value of an `#each` loop is assigned to `this`.

> The each-helper iterates an array, allowing you to access the
> properties of each object via simple handlebars expressions.
>
> ```
> <ul class="people_list">
>   {{#each people}}
>     <li>{{this}}</li>
>   {{/each}}
> </ul>
> ```